# Modifying existing jQuery function to add styles / modify classes with .find

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

This is my (condensed) markup:-

```
<section class="home-section clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title"><a href="#">The Title</a></h2>
        <div class="tagline description"><p>The Content</p></div>
        <img class="image" src="#" />
    </div>
</section>
```

I wish to make the title and description bounce in and fade in on page load. All the CSS for this is in place correctly, I just need to get the below jQuery function correct so that the relevant styles and classes are changed as needed to trigger all the CSS for these effects.

This is what I have:-

```
function et_slider_animate_items( active_slide ){
        var animation_speed = 400;

        active_slide.find( 'h2, .description' ).css( 'opacity', '0' ).end().find( '.et_animated_item' ).removeClass( 'et_animated_item' );

        setTimeout( function() {
            active_slide.find( 'img' ).addClass( 'et_animated_item' );

            setTimeout( function() {
                active_slide.find( '.description' ).addClass( 'et_animated_item' ).css( 'opacity', '1' );

                setTimeout( function() {
                    active_slide.find( 'h2' ).addClass( 'et_animated_item' ).css( 'opacity', '1' );
                }, animation_speed );
            }, animation_speed );
        }, animation_speed );
    }
```

`active_slide` is not currently defined anywhere and not needed so I wish to modify this function to look for the `h2`, `description` and `img` within the class `home-section`, `animate` if someone could please advise of the best way to modify what I've currently got, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of receiving `active_slide` as a parameter declare it as a local variable

```
function et_slider_animate_items() {
    var animation_speed = 400,
        active_slide = $('.home-section');

    active_slide.find('h2, .description').css('opacity', '0').end().find('.et_animated_item').removeClass('et_animated_item');

    setTimeout(function () {
        active_slide.find('img').addClass('et_animated_item');

        setTimeout(function () {
            active_slide.find('.description').addClass('et_animated_item').css('opacity', '1');

            setTimeout(function () {
                active_slide.find('h2').addClass('et_animated_item').css('opacity', '1');
            }, animation_speed);
        }, animation_speed);
    }, animation_speed);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not working despite your answer as making logical sense. I'd expect this to be adding the class `et_animated_item` to the `h2` and `.description` within `.home-section`? But it isn't currently, no class is getting added at all (there are no errors in the console either). Thanks.

Comment: I've now managed to get this working by getting rid of `active_slide` entirely but replacing `active_slide.find` with `jQuery` and this now works as expected (for some reason). Thanks.